# Repeated Automator workflow fails to run in Calendar

Tags: automator, calendar

I'm on Mac High Sierra and I've set up multiple daily repeated schedules (around 10 workflows) to run Automator workflow and the first few days it ran fine, but after a week the alarm just stops working. 
The schedule doesn't even show up in notification center anymore.

Does anyone know how to diagnose/fix this issue?

**Update**

Everything works fine if I open up Automator and run it manually, just that calendar alarm doesn't trigger Automator workflow anymore.

Comment: Can you share a screenshots with your Automator workflow?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've included one of the workflow, rest are pretty much the same except with different links. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/eIFNv) are the images.

Comment: Images didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Is your calendar in iCloud? I'm struggling to do the same thing. Automator calendar workflows need to be saved 'on my mac' but in my experience they get automatically shoved to iCloud, which does not support App Alerts. Try removing your Calendar iCloud syncing and then create your Automator calendar workflow.